# Chakra UI: Change option text color and option background in Select

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I have a select dropdown using ChakraUI, it like:

```
<Select color={"white"} bg={"black"}>
    <option value="option1">Option1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option2</option>
</Select>
```

When I click to dropdown, the option has both textColor and bgColor is white.
I want to change option appear that textColor is black and bgColor is white.
I have set color, bgColor in option field but it not working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to style the `<option>`s:

```
<Select bg="black" color="white">
  <option style={{ color: 'black' }} value="option1">
    Option1
  </option>
  <option style={{ color: 'black' }} value="option2">
    Option2
  </option>
</Select>;
```

Note that if you add a placeholder to `<Select>`, it will still be white on white when opened.

Another curious thing is that this problem does not happen in Safari, there the dropdown looks just like a standard OS menu.

Comment: Hello. How can I add a styled to selected option ? I struggle to achieve adding own background to specific selected option. thanks

Comment: Chakra uses regular [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#styling_with_css) and [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css) HTML elements, and those have very limited styling and don't produce consistent results across various browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Intended for those who have trouble with chakra-ui's select on Window's Chrome. Here is the simplest solution I come up with.

```
<Select
  ...
  bg='black'
  color: 'white'
  sx={{
    '> option': {
      background: 'black',
      color: 'white',
    },
  }}
>
```

Note: Only background and color can be edited for select's options. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css